# How to mock ValueMap in Spock framework in CQ5?

Tags: aem, spock

I am writing unit test cases using Spock framework for CQ5 project.

```
 def  props1 = Mock(ValueMap)
    props1.put("prop1",21);
    props1.put("prop2",92);
```

I am not able to add properties to props1.

Comment: Please don't just post snippets but tell us what you actually want to test. Show an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) rather than a snippet without any context. People on SO are developers, not mind readers. We need to understand **what** you want to achieve, not just **how** you think that should be done, because obviously it does not work the way you think it should. E.g., what do you want to do with the values in the map? Retrieve them again later? Please edit your post and notify us, then we can solve your problem. The solution depends on the information you provide.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with Spock but in Java tests you do not need to mock a `ValueMap`. Fortunately, there is a better way to create a `ValueMap` using `org.apache.sling.api.wrappers.ValueMapDecorator`:

```
final Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
properties.put("prop1", 21);
properties.put("prop2", 92);

final ValueMap valueMap = new ValueMapDecorator(properties);
```

Maybe you can adapt that for Spock.

Documentation:

https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/developing/using/reference-materials/javadoc/org/apache/sling/api/wrappers/ValueMapDecorator.html

https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/developing/using/reference-materials/javadoc/org/apache/sling/api/wrappers/ModifiableValueMapDecorator.html

Answer (score 0):

Well, I just took a break and needed something else to think about, so I made up a quick example for you. But before we look into the code, the explanation why you cannot call `put(..)` on a `Mock(ValueMap)`: simply because the interface [`ValueMap`](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/developing/using/reference-materials/javadoc/org/apache/sling/api/resource/ValueMap.html) only has `get(..)` methods. So you have two ways of testing with a `ValueMap`:

1. Use a real object as suggested by *Jens*. How to use the [`ValueMapDecorator`](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/developing/using/reference-materials/javadoc/org/apache/sling/api/wrappers/ValueMapDecorator.html) suggested by him can be seen in my first feature method.
2. Use a `Mock(ValueMap)` or, even better, just a `Stub(ValueMap)` and specify (stub) its behaviour when calling `get(..)` methods with values used during the test. This way you do not need to populate the real object with values and use a concrete class, but just tell the stubbed interface how to behave.

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow

import org.apache.sling.api.resource.ValueMap
import org.apache.sling.api.wrappers.ValueMapDecorator
import spock.lang.Specification

class SlingValueMapTest extends Specification {
  def "Real ValueMap"() {
    given:
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>()
    map.put("prop1", 21)
    map.put("prop2", 92)
    ValueMap valueMap = new ValueMapDecorator(map)

    expect:
    valueMap.get("prop1") == 21
    valueMap.get("foo") == null
    valueMap.get("prop2") == 92
    valueMap.get("bar") == null
  }

  def "Stubbed ValueMap"() {
    given:
    ValueMap valueMap = Stub() {
      get("prop1") >> 21
      get("prop2") >> 92
      get(_) >> null
    }

    expect:
    valueMap.get("prop1") == 21
    valueMap.get("foo") == null
    valueMap.get("prop2") == 92
    valueMap.get("bar") == null
  }
}
```